# How to apply xslt template to parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having some trouble adding html to parent of selected node. I have a xml document:

```
<component>
    <section>
        <text>
            <content>
              some text 1
            </content>
            <content>
              some text 2
            </content>
        </text> 
    </section>
    <section>
        <text>
            <otherElements></otherElements>
        </text> 
    </section>
    .....
</component>
```

There are many sections, some with content element under text element and some not. I only template to apply to ones with content element and have output where i have one table for every text element and one row for every content element :

```
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr><td>some text 1</td>
         <tr><td>some text 2</td>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

When i select content element with

```
<xsl:template match="section/text/content">
```

I am able to add rows to it but i am not sure how to add table and tbody tags to the parent node. If i start with

```
<xsl:template match="section/text">
```

It also adds to text elements with otherElements also which i don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `match="section/text [content]"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do (untested, just to illustrate the idea):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//component/section[text/content]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[text/content]">
    <table><tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text/content"/>
    </tbody></table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>
```